# AArch64 execution stops after ERET when trying to switch to a lower exception level

Tags: assembly, arm64, bare-metal

I have started a bare-metal application for AArch64 for the purpose of education. It works fine, when I don't change the exception level to a lower one. But when I want to try to change the exception level from `EL2` to `EL1` the CPU seems to hang after the `ERET` instruction.

My current startup code:

```
#include <asm.h>

IMPORT_ASM(_cpu_el3_vec_tbl_set)
IMPORT_ASM(_cpu_el2_vec_tbl_set)
IMPORT_ASM(_cpu_el1_vec_tbl_set)

IMPORT_C(init)
IMPORT_C(main)

.text

ENTRY(_start)
    mrs x0, MPIDR_EL1
    and x0, x0, #0x3
    cmp x0, #0
    beq __elx

__wfe_cpu1_3:
    wfe
    b __wfe_cpu1_3
    
__elx:
__el3:
    mrs x0, CurrentEL
    and x0, x0, #0xC
    asr x0, x0, #2
    cmp x0, #3
    bne __el2
__el3_stack:
    ldr x0, =_stack_el3_e
    mov sp, x0
__el3_vector:
    bl _cpu_el3_vec_tbl_set
    msr SCTLR_EL2, xzr
    msr HCR_EL2, xzr
    mrs x0, SCR_EL3
    orr x0, x0, #(1<<10)
    orr x0, x0, #(1<<0)
    msr SCR_EL3, x0
    mov x0, #0b01001
    msr SPSR_EL3, x0
    adr x0, __el2
    msr ELR_EL3, x0
    eret
    
__el2:
    mrs x0, CurrentEL
    and x0, x0, #0xC
    asr x0, x0, #2
    cmp x0, #2
    bne __el1
__el2_stack:
    ldr x0, =_stack_el2_e
    mov sp, x0
__el2_vector:
    bl _cpu_el2_vec_tbl_set
    msr SCTLR_EL1, xzr
    mov x0, xzr
    orr x0, x0, #(1 << 31)
    msr HCR_EL2, x0
    /*orr x0, x0, #(7 << 6) */
    adr x0, __el1
    mov x1, xzr
    orr x1, x1, #(1 << 2)
    orr x1, x1, #(1 << 0)
    msr SPSR_EL2, x1
    msr ELR_EL2, x0
    eret
    
__el1:
__el1_stack:
    ldr x0, =_stack_el1_e
    mov sp, x0
__el1_vector:
    bl _cpu_el1_vec_tbl_set
    
    ldr x0, =_bss_s
    ldr x1, =_bss_e
    sub x1, x1, x0
    mov x2, #0x0
    cbz x1, __init
__bss:
    strb w2, [x0], #1
    sub x1, x1, #1
    cbnz x1, __bss
    
__init:
    bl init

__main:
    bl main
__main_wfe:
    wfe
    b __main_wfe

.end
```

When I comment out the section between label `__elx` to `__el1` it works (the C function `init` and `main` will be executed). I have also tried to place the `init` (currently only contains a function, which prints out the current exception level over UART) before and after the `ERET` instruction. The result is, that the `init` call after `ERET` will be never executed.

No idea what's going wrong here.

**EDIT:**
I have also created a vector table with handlers for `EL2` and `EL1`. But unfortunately no exception will be thrown.

**UPDATE:**
Okay, `EL1` will be entered. But I have some strange issues with some parts of my C code when running in `EL1`:

*First:*
The execution from the C code is (subjectively) slower in `EL1` than in `EL2`.

*Second:*
Some parts from the C code (my `sprintf` implementation) are not called. The strange thing here is with `sprintf`, it works without issues in `EL2`.

Is there maybe a wrong configuration of `HCR_EL2` and/or `SCTLR_EL1`?
Currently I initialize `HCR_EL2` and `SCTLR_EL1` with zero and set the `RW` bit (AArch64 state) in `HCR_EL2`.

Comment: "Bare-metal Boot Code for ARMv8-A Processors" manual has working example how to navigate between level. https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dai0527/a/

Comment: Switching into EL1 looks fine. Should you also init MMU after switching into EL1 and before calling init/main ? And as a guess that slower EL1 by a chance caused by some regular occurring interrupts/exceptions

Comment: @user3124812 Okay, thanks. But I already know this documentation. My current code is based on the code sample in chapter 5.5 (AArch64 EL3 to AArch64 EL0). Changing to EL1 works in assembly, but when I call C functions from startup I have noticed two behaviors. First the execution speed is slower than in EL2 (Currently I use U-Boot to start the application which setup EL2). The second behavior is that some functions in C code not will be called. The processor hangs at specific functions. When I don't change to EL1, than everything works. Also the C functions. No idea what's going wrong here.

Comment: @user3124812 I have unmasked the interrupts now with `msr DAIFclr, #7` before i call the `init` function. I have also created vector tables for both EL1 and EL2. In the handlers I currently simple print the IRQ number via UART. But they don't get called. VBAR_EL2 and VBAR_EL1 are set.

Comment: I just love these questions with miles of uncommented assembly code.  Shows how much effort was put into making it understandable.

Comment: After sleeping on it, performance drop could be as simple as turned off caches. If U-Boot turns caches on for EL2, after switching to EL1, code execution on EL1 would start with MMU and caches disabled.

Comment: "The processor hangs at specific functions. ", I'd check how that linked and what addressed that code uses. If indeed U-boot on EL2 has MMU enabled, and EL1 has it disabled, all could boil down to differences in memory address translations.

Comment: @user3124812 Sorry for my late response. I have tried to enable the MMU. Had some troubles with the pagetables and the configuration. But still hangs on specific functions. Might be there some issues with the stack pointer?

Comment: I don't know what makes you think about stack. But first check you linker map that `_stack_el1_e` is 16Byte aligned. Secondly make a function which declares `uint32_t [stack_size - expected_used_stack]` and fill array with a value in a loop. Run a few times and find a size when program start to crash. You would know how much stack left for your troublesome function. Make `objdump` and check how much stack that troublesome function uses. Normally that's a first line which decrement stack pointer `sub sp, sp, #80` (reserve 80Bytes for stack).